# Why is my object appearing as a series of incomplete lines in the 3D view?

Tags: modeling

So I was just modeling a Pokeball to upload to Deviant Art for fun. And as soon as I left the live preview in object mode as seen here(Picture 1)[image: live preview],

I went to start adjusting the camera only to be greeted with this(Picture 2).[image: object mode]

The mesh is still fine in edit mode. I am just wondering what it is and why Blender is replacing the spheres with what would belong to a science fiction game.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check your Viewport Shading

Comment: post a picture that shows the settings for your subsurf modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change viewport shading from Wireframe to Rendered, Material, Texture or Solid.

[image]

To display all the edges in Wireframe Shading enable **Draw All Edges** in Object Data tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when a 'Subsurf' modifier is applied with high 'subdivision' values. And when you enter 'Edit mode' and exit it to 'Object mode', then the mesh is almost invisible in 'wireframe shading'. Switching from 'wireframe' to any other shading and back to 'wireframe' is not a solution, unless you want to view it in 'solid mode'. In 'solid shading' the mesh is visible, but I think you want to know how to make the mesh visible in 'wireframe shading' :)

A solution could be to again apply a 'Subsurf' modifier, but set the 'render' value to 0, and 'view' value to 1. So the 'extra' 'subsurf' will not be rendered, but it will make the mesh visible in the 3D view.

Answer (score 0):

For 2.8X Series viewport shading can be adjusted from the popovers on the 3DView header, above the viewport to the right.

[image]

Object Display properties and overrides are still in the *Properties Window > Object > Viewport  Display* as before.