# Sculpt mode not showing the vertices/faces of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm not sure why but my plane isn't showing any vertices or faces in sculpt mode. I'm trying to sculpt terrain, so I created a plane, and subdivided the surface, then applied that subdivision.

When I enter sculpt mode, it only shows the outline, although the sculpting changes take effect. How do I see the individual faces of the object and why aren't they showing up automatically?

[image]

Comment: You are in wireframe shading

Comment: in the Proprties->Object->Display->Display all edges check this

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31029/why-is-my-object-appearing-as-a-series-of-incomplete-lines-in-the-3d-view/31032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Properties** area in the **Object** tab under the **Display** panel check **Draw all edges**

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's not working in 2.76

Comment: Instead of it option 'wire' works good